# SQL Server getdate() method to return region specific date

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3 databases hosted on different servers on different regions. We are heavily relying on sorted procedures and using `getdate()` function.
We are getting results based on server region.

We have to pay licencing cost of 3 servers, is there any possibility to host all databases on same server without affecting `getdate()` functionality?

I mean on same server, `getdate()` for
db1 - returns UK date
db2 - returns NL date
db3 - returns US date

If it's not possible in SQL Server then, is it possible any other relational database.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: UTC is the great equalizer.  No worries about DST (which should be banned) and it is a small matter to transform to/from local time on the client.

Comment: Removed Postgres tag. There is no GETDATE function in Postgres.

Comment: @AaronBertrand not possible to use UTC as I have lot of data already stored with their respected time zones. To use UTC I have to fix the existing data by converting it into UTC. Also I need to update my application to handle UTC dates and converts to respected time zones. 
Plus need a way to handle Daylight saving. Your is perfect for new start but I am hesitant to use it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no, this is not possible; the advice in the comments of "use UTC" is good.

The (only slightly longer) answer is: any given database gets its notion of date from the database engine which in turn gets the time from the operating system hosting it. So, if three databases are ultimately hosted on the same host OS, calls to `getdate()` are going to return the same.

---

Now is the time for Bad Ideas™. This is possible in MSSQL 2016 and above:

```
declare @tz1 varchar(40) = 'UTC',
    @tz2 varchar(40) = 'Central European Standard Time',
    @tz3 varchar(40) = 'Pacific Standard Time',
    @time datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset();

select @time at time zone @tz1 as [UK],
    @time at time zone @tz2 as [EU],
    @time at time zone @tz3 as [US];

select cast(@time at time zone @tz1 as datetime) as [UK],
    cast(@time at time zone @tz2 as datetime) as [EU],
    cast(@time at time zone @tz3 as datetime) as [US];
```

You could imagine having a one row, one column table in each of the respective databases that holds "what time zone should I report times in?" and use that value in place of `@tz`. Or a per-database UDF that hard codes its time zone into it and returns times in the "correct" time zone. Like I said - Bad Ideas™.

Comment: This solution might work for me with some changes to handle 'day light saving' handling

Comment: The `at time zone` syntax handles daylight savings already.